# Can't install wine in Kali 2020.4

Tags: kali-linux, wine

I can't just install it, I watched all guides I could but the same problem appears

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update && apt-get install wine32
```

and this appears:

```
Reading package list ... Done
E: Could not open lock file "/ var / lib / apt / lists / lock" - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Could not lock directory / var / lib / apt / lists /
W: There was a problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: There was a problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

Comment: 1) `sudo` stops at the `&&` barrier, so you're not running apt as root. 2) Kali linux is primarily a pentesting tool and an *incredibly* poor choice for desktop OS, especially for someone who - judging by your question - has very limited experience with linux in general.

Answer (score 1):

You're running `dpkg` with `sudo` , but `apt-get` without. After each `&&` you have a new command and need another `sudo`:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine32
```